# Is there a way to change the unibyte string bytecode output of `byte-compile` to hex?

Tags: byte-compilation, bytecode

Given a byte-compiled function:

```lisp
(byte-compile (defun factorial (integer)
                "Compute factorial of an integer."
                (if (= 1 integer) 1
                  (* integer (factorial (1- integer))))))
=> #[(integer)
     "\301U\203\0\301\207\302S!_\207"
     [integer 1 factorial]
     3 "Compute factorial of an integer."]
```

Is there a way to change the unibyte string bytecode to hex (or decimal (any any other which-way to make it more readable))?

Comment: Does the `disassemble` command count? See [`(info "(elisp) Disassembly")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Disassembly.html).

Comment: I already utilize that. What I want to see is the string in hex.